# Verbatim. How to deal with it automatically?

Tags: verbatim, automation

I have a rather big LaTeX file, which was created by another person. It is a description of some code with results of its run. It is full of `\verbatim` blocks.

Now I should create 2 pdf files from it. The first file should be just without any `\verbatim` blocks. The second should be with them, but comments which are inside (`'\\'`) should be marked by color or bold.

Is it possible to do it without manual deletion, and splitting `\verbatim` blocks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can do a global search and replace to make all your `verbatim` environments into `lstlisting` environments, this will work. Without a more explicit example, I'm not sure how you're defining a comment that will be treated differently than other items in the `verbatim` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

% For version without code
%\usepackage{comment}
%\excludecomment{lstlisting}

% For version with code
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\lstset{language=C,basicstyle=\ttfamily,showstringspaces=false,commentstyle=\color{red}}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
#include <stdio.h>
void main(void) {
  printf("Hello, world!\n");
  /* A comment */
}
\end{lstlisting}
Some other text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good deal. Mark it as accepted (check mark icon to the side of the answer), and it will be removed from the unanswered list.